# Cause of P2263 on 2011 Acura RDX

Tags: turbocharger, acura, waste-gate, rdx

I'm investigating a P2263 error on my 2011 RDX SHAWD. The wastegate valve eyelet has been adjusted so there is no slack, but still the P2263 appears - but only after a few hours of driving.

I looked at the freeze frame data at the time of error, and Baro=97kpa and TCBoost = 1.45kpa. The code was set at a time that I was not (I think) calling for turbo.

From what I read the PCM sees sensor/actuator values that don't match what's expect.  But that's too vague to diagnose.  Can someone offer more specifics on what conditions set the P2263 on this vehicle?